# My rfid-rc522 reader stops reading after some time, how can I debug it?

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, rfid

I'm using the reader below to read mifare cards (13.56mhz), I have an electron/node.js application for this. For some reason after an uncertain amount of time(shortest time I noticed was about 30 minutes) the reader just stops reading, but the power is still on indicated by a red LED on the reader.

[I'm using this to do the card reading and also followed the gpio wiring shown](https://github.com/firsttris/mfrc522-rpi). I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong since I only experience this on my Pi 3 Model B+(2017), I also have Pi 4's which I don't experience this in. Sometimes restarting the application works and it can read again, sometimes I have to reboot the pi itself. Both are running buster, updated. Same application.

[image]

Comment: add some console.log's to the code where you suspect it may be failing

Comment: @JaromandaX I already tried debugging the section of the javascript code responsible for reading the card, it's not detecting any card at all.

Comment: so, you can still successfully communicate with the RC522, it just doesn't detect cards?

Comment: does the issue occur after a specific number of reads?

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't really tell since the part of the code that detects cards will just keep looping until it detects one, even if there is something wrong with the reader or there is even no reader. The code doesn't detect if a reader is present or something is wrong.

Comment: @jsotola No, as far as I can tell right now it just stops reading when it's not in used for a while.

Comment: anything in any system logs that may point to an issue? maybe a momentary power issue?

Comment: @JaromandaX how can I check that?

Comment: by inspecting the system logs - bunch of them in /var/log folder

Comment: @JaromandaX browsed a few of them like syslog, user.log, boot, kern. didn't find anything that caught my attention, anything I should be looking for?

Comment: *maybe a momentary power issue* was one suggestion ... also, are you using SPI or I2C connection for that RC522?

Comment: @JaromandaX SPI

Comment: @JaromandaX I checked the logs again and I did find under-voltage warnings. Would that cause the reader to stop working? currently the things connected to the pi are the reader, a fan(5v), a monitor(4.3 inch lcd) connected via usb and hdmi. My power for the pi is a 5.1v