# MCP23S17 and multiple RFID-RC522 Modules

Tags: gpio

Good day all,

I am trying to connect a range of RC522 RFID modules to an IO expander MCP23S17 run by a RPI. I am having trouble finding information regarding editing the MFRC522.py modules to allow a change of CS pin. Has anyone attempted or know of reading materials that can point me in the right direction?

https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/tree/master/mfrc522

To clarify:
I am looking for information regarding switching between RC522 modules one at a time connected to IO expander MCP23S17. So will be calling a IO pin from MCP23S17 as a designated CS pin for the RC522 module and reading a RFID tag on a selected RFID reader. The way of which I can do this, I require some insights. Many thanks

Comment: Not really a Pi question.  It's more of how do I change/write a program type of question.

Comment: Did I assume wrong this was a "Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi"?

Comment: @j01010, Welcome and nice to meet you. (1) Rpi is OK to use pimylifeup/MFRC522-python for RFID apps. (2) MCP23S17 GPIO pins to reset/chip select RC-522 looks like a good design approach. (3) You might like to search RpiSE, SO and EESE for my answers to RFID/NFC questions.

Comment: You might like to skim my old answers on various questions on NFC and RFID. You might find references on them useful for your projects: (1) Raspberry Pi , RFID , Relay Module and Magnetic Door - RpiSE
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/raspberry-pi-rfid-relay-module-and-magnetic-door/124335#124335

(2) Can RFID read stacked cards? - EESE
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519993/can-rfid-read-stacked-cards

(3) How can Rpi read a PN532 NFC Module? - SO
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165652/how-can-rpi-read-a-pn532-nfc-module

Comment: For 017 and s17, you might like to skim my some 200+ (yes, 200+! :)) answers in Rpi.org.forum: Search found 178 + 27 matches: mcp23017 tlfong01, mcp23s17 tlfong01
(4) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=mcp23s17+tlfong01
(5) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=mcp23017+tlfong01. As you know, 017 and s17 have the same internal architecture, except interface SPI and I2C, so many tricks are common. Cheers.