# Can I use the Solenoid lock without an external power supply?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, relay

I have a question about the Solenoid lock: can I use it with a 12v relay module without an external power supply?

I'm using Raspberry pi 3 model B.

Comment: Yes, you can use batteries, eg, Lip0, lead acid etc: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/raspberry-pi-rfid-relay-module-and-magnetic-door/124335#124335

Comment: @tlfong01 a battery is an external power supply

Comment: There's only 3.3V & 5V available on an RPi so you'd need a buck converter to run a 12V solenoid. It would be possible if the current draw for the buck converter & solenoid is tiny but you'll be better off with a battery or 12V external power supply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about "the Solenoid lock". (Model, type, link to data sheet.) Electromagnetic components draw a fairly high current and and can create currents when switched off. You normally need an external transistor and protective circuitry like a flyback diode or maybe even a relay, and external power supply.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I think you didn't get my question someone told me that I can use relay module with 12v without needing an external power supply so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your question is a bit vague. Perhaps the best answer is to show a couple of alternatives *schematically*:

I'll assume that your reference to `"a 12v relay module without an external power supply"` is blether, and your question is rather how to supply 12V of power to a **Solenoid-driven door lock**.

The answer to that question is an unqualified *"it depends on how much power is required"*! Shown below are two approaches:

###### Option 1:

***IF*** your Solenoid doesn't require more than say 100 milliamps of current at 12VDC, you may be able to add a DC-DC converter to boost the 5V RPi Supply up to 12VDC as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fApqh3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

###### Option 2:

But unless you've got a substantial 5V RPi supply, I think the external supply may be a better option - shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwOhw7.png)</sup>

#### Other Details:

These schematics aren't detailed enough to actually build a circuit. That's because you didn't give enough information to support these details. Suggest you now do a bit of homework, and edit your question to make it clear enough to allow someone to help with a properly detailed answer.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.